# Как запретить прямое отображение каталогов веб-сайта?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, веб-сервер, apache2

Есть публичная папка, куда грузятся все пользовательские файлы:

```
public/loaded/
```

Как запретить прямой перебор путей и отображения файлов: `public/loaded/user/2014/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрет отображения содержания каталога:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Перенаправление запросов к файлам не через ваш сайт:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*yourdomain.ru.* [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$  
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://redirect_url/$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*) http://redirect_url/$ [R=301,L]` дает циклический редирект

Comment: Тогда можно просто запретить доступ (403):

    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [F]

Comment: В таком случай даже исполнительные файлы не исполняются). Т.е. полный запрет на все каталоги.

Answer (score 0):

Options -Indexes + кастомные rewwriterule, если требуется отдавать 404 по конкретным паттернам

http://wildlifedamage.unl.edu/manual/mod/core.html#options